# Beacons didRange called but didEnter is not?

Tags: swift, ibeacon

When the beacon is **off** I always get `didRange` fired, and `didEnter` is **not** fired even when I turn on the beacon . (set all keys on info)

Setting the beacon :

```
    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }



    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935")!, identifier: "Me")
    region.notifyOnEntry=true;
    region.notifyOnExit=true;
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)


    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestStateForRegion(region)
```

The delegates :

```
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {


        print("didRangeBeacons");  // keep being called always


  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {


        print("enter region"); // never happen
```

I would like to get both of them called, so I can check the **value** inside `didRange`, but I will also be able to send push only on `EnterRegion`

Comment: Are you positive the beacon is transmitting the UUID of 74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935?  Can you detect it with an off the shelf tool like Locate? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8

Comment: If it wasn't I wouldn't have get the didRangeBeacon delegate with the right minor and major values. So I guess I am positive :) thanks. I'v removed the app and installed it again, this solve the first problem so didRangeBeacon now only happens when beacon, but still didEnter is not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously :)

```
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
```

**only** start **ranging**, to ***monitor*** you need :

```
     locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
```

Comment: Good eye.  That would do it!